# Upgrading the BIOS on Lenovo IdeaPad B50-70 Without Windows

Tags: lenovo, bios

I would like to upgrade my Lenovo B50-70's BIOS. The only options for OS on the product's [Site](http://goo.gl/mbBvLa) are Windows 7 and 8.

When I try to run the EXE file inside Hiren's MiniXP it claims the system battery is missing (although it's plugged in). I extracted the EXE file and found the BIOS .ROM file, but there's no way to install it. The Insyde20.exe program works only in Windows.

Obviously, I won't install a full version of windows just to upgrade the BIOS...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a live windows session inside a usb drive. But even for that u might need a windows pc/laptop. Not sure if u can run that software inside ubuntu.

http://lifehacker.com/how-to-run-a-portable-version-of-windows-from-a-usb-dri-1565509124